# How to control the layout of an HTML page so that the body stops at x pixels from bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<body>
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->

<div id="header">

</div>
<!--topic-content-->

<div id="content">
<table id="topic-content" style="height: 100%; width: 90%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%; vertical-align: top;" id="start-panel">
            <!--start-panel-->
                <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="loading">
                          <script type="text/javascript">
                                var loading = "Loading...";
                                if(typeof resources != "undefined" && typeof resources != null){
                                    if (resources["Loading"] || resources["Loading"] != "") 
                                        loading = resources["Loading"]; 
                                }
                                                            document.write(loading);
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!--footer--> 
    </table>
</div>

<!-- The configuration section -->
<div style="display: none;">

</div>


</body>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwLgZr (sensitive info removed), that imports (through javascript) an HTML page and displays it in the window (below the header, if there is one) but the issue is that if I add a footer, it continues to flow under the footer. How can I have it so that the section stops above the footer?

[Left is what I have now, right is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoR7p.png)

Comment: Have you tried `body { height: calc(100vh - 50px); overflow:auto;}`?

Comment: Please fix your codepen and post the generated code, we don't need to wait for JavaScript to load content for demonstration sake. Also, looking at your photo, do you want the scrollbar to be limited to content?

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless you use frames or iframes, but I would advise against them.

Answer (score 0):

your sample code is quite confusing. Anyway I made a proof of concept that meets your requirements. Actually you have to have a container with scroll enabled and another element to perform the footer role.

The idea is have a container with a fixed height (using the vh unit – Vertical Height Percentage), and the scrolling content inside it. And right after, a footer with fixed height.

HTML

```
<section>
  <div class="content">
   [All your content here]
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  HI
</footer>
```

CSS

```
section {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Please refer to the codepen for complete solution:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVREJw

Have fun!

Comment: Note this solution is IE9+